# A java program that displays weekly payroll for 5 employees (error in desired output)

Tags: java, compiler-errors, runtime-error

My coding is based on this question:
[screenshot of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XUGx.png)

And this is what I've coded and it's completed but I have an error in the desired output.

```js
package assignment_2;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment_2 {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        String employeeName[] = new String[5];
        int employeeID[] = new int[5];
        int payStatus[] = new int[5];
        double Grosspay[] = new double [5];
        int workHours[] = new int[5];
        double payRateperhour[] = new double [5];
        double incomeTax[] = new double [5];
        double netPay[] = new double [5];
        
        
        
        System.out.println("Enter 5 employee details.");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String nextLine = input.nextLine(); //skip whitespace error
            System.out.print("Enter Employee " + (i+1) + " name: "); //prompt user input for employee name
            employeeName[i] = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter Employee " + (i+1) + " ID: "); //prompt user input for employee ID
            employeeID[i] = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter Employee " + (i+1) + " pay status (1 = Salary or 2 = Hourly): "); //prompt user input for employee paid by salary or hourly?
            payStatus[i] = input.nextInt();
            if (payStatus[i] == 1){ //pay by salary user input
                System.out.print("Enter employee gross pay(RM): ");
                Grosspay[i] = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Enter employee work hours per week: ");
                workHours[i] = input.nextInt();
            } else { //pay by hourly user input
                System.out.print("Enter employee pay rate per hour(RM): ");
                payRateperhour[i] = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Enter employee work hours per week: ");
                workHours[i] = input.nextInt();
                //calculate overtime pay
                if (workHours[i] > 40) {
                    Grosspay[i] = (40 * payRateperhour[i]) + 1.5 * (workHours[i] - 40) * payRateperhour[i];
                } else Grosspay[i] = workHours[i] * payRateperhour[i];

            }
        
        //calculate income tax
        if (Grosspay[i] > 0.00 || Grosspay[i] < 999.99) {
            incomeTax[i] = (8 /100) * Grosspay[i];
        } else if (Grosspay[i] > 500.00 || Grosspay[i] < 999.99) {
            incomeTax[i] = (10 /100) * Grosspay[i];
        } else if (Grosspay[i] > 1000.00) {
            incomeTax[i] = (15 /100) * Grosspay[i];
        } else
            
        //calculate net pay 
        netPay[i] = Grosspay[i] - incomeTax[i];
        
    }
//Display employee details and weekly salary
        System.out.print("\n\n\t\tPrint Daily Company (PDC)\n\t\t   Weekly Payroll Data\n");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("   Name\t\tID#\tGross Pay\tTax\tNet Pay");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(employeeName[i] + "\t" + employeeID[i] + "\t" + Grosspay[i] + "\t" + incomeTax[i] + "\t" + netPay[i]);
                    }
        
    }
    
}
```

My error is that it does not calculate the income tax. In the output it shows 0.00. And the net pay is being outputted the same amount as the gross pay. And one of the outputs from a given sample I keyed in my program showed more than 2 decimal places unlike the rest of the outputs.

P.s: I also didn't know how to fix the error of whitespace os skipping an input line. So I just inserted String nextLine = input.nextLine(); //skip whitespace error before all the user inputs. (If anyone can help me with that or teach/show me a smooth output, that'd be great)

Thank you in advance.

Below is how my output looks like in case anyone was wondering.
[screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHn7O.jpg)

[UPDATE]:
This is the updated output for my program. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWF0J.jpg) My net pay isn't working and so as the decimal point value. Still in need of help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this little "problem" is not that easy to catch. 
But in essence, Java tricked you by rounding numbers. Every time you used (8 / 100) or any other of the calculations for the income tax, java just rounded them to 0, because integer / integer is interpreted as integer result. The easiest way to fix it, is just to add .0 to each 100.

```
    if (Grosspay[i] > 0.00 || Grosspay[i] < 999.99) {
        incomeTax[i] = (8 / 100.0) * Grosspay[i];
    } else if (Grosspay[i] > 500.00 || Grosspay[i] < 999.99) {
        incomeTax[i] = (10 / 100.0) * Grosspay[i];
    } else if (Grosspay[i] > 1000.00) {
        incomeTax[i] = (15 / 100.0) * Grosspay[i];
    }
```

This should work.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked.

But my net pay is still not working. It just shows 0.0.